# Proper use of pronouns and conjunctions

Tags: pronouns, conjunctions

Could someone please verify the grammar in this sentence? Particularly the use of 'her' (should it be she?) and the implied 'her' after the and. Should there be a second 'her'?

"They sought treatment for symptoms related to her already diagnosed Generalized Anxiety Disorder and marked episodes of anger and oppositional behavior. "

Comment: Seems perfectly fine as is.

Comment: *Diagnosed* and *marked* are passive participles modifying the following nouns, not verbs cast in the past tense. "Symptoms related to her ... GAD and ... episodes" is the object of the preposition "for".

Comment: I don't want to leave this question unanswered. Jim or Stoney, if either of you want to copy your comment into answer, please do. Thanks, both, for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For readability, I would make it a little clearer what parts of speech *diagnosed* and *marked* have in this sentence. Grammatically, you have correctly expressed that *diagnosed* refers to her GAD and *marked* is an adjective referring to her episodes, but someone skimming the sentence may not immediately appreciate that. Instead, perhaps:

> They sought treatment for symptoms related to her **already-diagnosed** Generalized Anxiety Disorder, and **her** marked episodes of anger and oppositional behavior.